# racket lambda order explanation

Tags: lambda, racket

```
(define povrch-valce
(lambda (V h)
((lambda (r)
(* 2 r pi (+ r h)))
(sqrt (/ V pi h)))))
```

If I understand this correctly (V h) are parameters and the body is:
`((lambda (r)
( * 2 r pi (+ r h)))
(sqrt (/ V pi h)))`

Then we have lambda(r), the parameter is (r) and body is:

```
(* 2 r pi (+ r h)))
(sqrt (/ V pi h)))))
```

Can some explain me please in what order is this last body processed? I dont understand how is (sqrt (/ V pi h)) calculated first even when its second in order.

Answer (score 1):

Using an editor that aligns properly the code, like DrRacket, the function has the following form:

```
(define povrch-valce
  (lambda (V h)
    ((lambda (r)
       (* 2 r pi (+ r h)))
     (sqrt (/ V pi h)))))
```

that is, `povrch-valce` is a function with two parameters, `V` and `h`, whose body is:

```
((lambda (r)
   (* 2 r pi (+ r h)))
 (sqrt (/ V pi h)))))
```

that is (note the two parentheses):

```
(f (sqrt (/ V pi h)))
```

where `f` is the function:

```
(lambda (r)
  (* 2 r pi (+ r h)))
```

that is a function applied the the result of the `sqrt` call.

So, the steps of evaluation of something like `(povrch-valce 2 3)` are the followings:

1. Calculate `(sqrt (/ V pi h))`; the result is 0.46065886596178063
2. Pass this value the the function f; the result is 10.016548388032545
3. This is the value returned by the initial call.